# How can I compile CoffeeScript AST into CoffeeScript instead of JavaScript?

Tags: coffeescript, abstract-syntax-tree

Is it possible to turn the AST back into CoffeeScript instead of into JavaScript? A project I am working basically requires turning all the CoffeeScript into the AST, analysing the AST, then turning portions of the AST back into CoffeeScript. I understand the transformation back would be 'lossy' with regards to the original code, but this is okay.

I would really like to avoid having to compile those portions to JavaScript and then back to CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See round_trip.coffee in [CoffeeCoffee](https://github.com/showell/CoffeeCoffee) project (I'm the author):

I don't cover every case, but it's a start.

Comment: This looks promising! I am a bit over my head here though...
How (in the browser environment) would I be able to input portion of the AST and receive coffeescript code back? Is that even possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but it requires you to play with Coffeescript's source code. You need to get familiar with the way Coffeescript does the tokenization, then how it turns tokens into the AST. The source code in question is in [coffee-script/src](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/tree/master/src) on Github.

If you look into the file [coffee-script/src/nodes.coffee](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/tree/master/src/nodes.coffee), you'll see a bunch of Node subclasses, each with their own compilation functions (like `compile()`, `compileNode()`, etc.). These define how the tree is turned into javascript code. If you want to generate Coffeescript code instead, you need to override all of them, on your own fork of the project.